# KiCad 'Silkscreen overlap' for 'Circle' and 'Rect' that don't appear to overlap

Tags: kicad

When I run the Design Rules Checker in KiCad, I get a warning about 'Silkscreen overlap' for 'Circle' and 'Rect'. But, these don't appear to overlap to me (from a certain point of view). It seems that the warning comes from putting circles inside a rectangle.

Interestingly, I tried converting the rectangle to discreet lines and still got the warning. Only when I separated the lines so that there was a gap, did the warning disappear. This seems odd to me that the DRC would consider this a problem.

Is this warning actually something to consider? For instance, is this something that silkscreen printers actually might struggle with somehow, or is it safe to ignore because the KiCad DRC simply doesn't consider the case of circles within rectangles?

[image: DRC control]

[image: PCB editor]

For now, I'll just exclude the violation.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that you have multiple components copied over top of each other?  (The text of J4,J5,J6 show as doubled.)  The small DRC arrows seem to point out items on the left side of the 2 pads, try clearing the DRC markers and adjust the silk screen (or component) that is crossing at the arrow points.  The DRC may just be warning that there is a possible component overlap just because the silkscreens overlap.  If needed you might revise the footprint of the component, (use Edit with ModEdit).

Comment: The DRC warning goes away when the rectangle is moved so that the circles are no longer inside. Therefore I can only conclude that the warning relates only to the silkscreen (and nothing else). I can confirm that there are no components that overlap, and the male pins having the same value is not a problem.